# Iconfont too small even with good px size

Tags: html, css, icons, glyphicons

I created fonts with gulp-iconfont. Had bunch of svg images. I can see them in my page but they are too small. I am missing something obvious but can't seem to find it.

```
<div class="slider show" alt="" style="">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <span><i class="s s-prev left-arrow"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <h1 class="title">
                            Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <span><i class="s s-next right-arrow"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <p class="text">
                            At vero eos et accusamus et iusto 
                            odio dignissimos ducimus qui 
                            blanditiis praesentium voluptatum 
                            deleniti atque corrupti
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <button type="button" class="btn" style="background-image: url(./images/button_arrow_white.png);">Contact us</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have two icons in this part. Left and right arrow. Here is the CSS part.

```
.s-prev , .s-next{
background-color: $white;
font-size: 65px;
color: black;
display: block;
}

.s-prev {
    float: left;
}

.s-next {
    float: right;
}
.arrow {
margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I snapped a pic to show you the icon.
[image]

You can see a small black dot inside. But it is 65px so it should be bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.s { font-size: 65px!important;}`

Comment: @Bojan, is the icon a .svg file or a web font?

Comment: I used "iconfont" to turn .svg into font